# jQuery callback function issue

Tags: jquery

I am a bit new to programming in jQuery/Javascript and am having some issues showing/hiding a series of headers in a div tag (container). The script code with attempted callback is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<h1>Text1</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000, function(){
        $("#container h1").fadeOut(2000, function(){
            $('<h1>Text2</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                $("#container h1").fadeOut(2000, function(){
                    $('<h1>Text3</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                        $("#container h1").fadeOut(2000, function(){
                            $('<h1>Text4</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I basically want it to dislay Tesxt1 header with a fadein, then fadeout, then desplay text2 with a fadein and fadeout. Text4 is the last one and should only have a fadein without fadeout. Without the callback functions, everything is executed simultaneously and when they are added (incorrectly) above, later texts are prepended multiple times.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: <<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>> :-) Are you writing code or doing some ASCII art?

Comment: sorry, the bold above is simply the header tags h1 Text1 /h1 with <>, so on.

Comment: I'm writing code and the original code without callback is: $('<h1>Text1</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000);
$("#container h1").fadeOut(2000);
$('<h1>Text2</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000);
$("#container h1").fadeOut(2000);
$('<h1>Text3</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000);
$("#container h1").fadeOut(2000);
$('<h1>Text4</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container").fadeIn(2000);

Comment: It would be a lot easier for people to answer if you're able to provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which exhibits your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and hide your elements first and then animate them.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/wPVsE/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text1 = $('<h1>Text1</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container");
    var text2 = $('<h1>Text2</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container");
    var text3 = $('<h1>Text3</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container");
    var text4 = $('<h1>Text4</h1>').hide().prependTo("#container");
    text1.fadeIn(2000, function(){
        text1.fadeOut(2000, function(){
            text2.fadeIn(2000, function(){
                text2.fadeOut(2000, function(){
                    text3.fadeIn(2000, function(){
                        text3.fadeOut(2000, function(){
                            text4.fadeIn(2000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent and quick answer. Thank you very much Craig M! I'll keep jsFiddle in mind next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I consider a much cleaner, more maintainable, and more extensible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/8GAN8/

You start off the animation on the first array element, give it the nextStep you want done once it completes (through the use of Promises), and then have each nextStep recursively call itself until you reach the last "frame" of the animation.